# Backpropagation from scratch in C++

Tags: c++, machine-learning, backpropagation, sigmoid

I'm trying to code a Neural Network with Backpropagation for teaching, using [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/implement-backpropagation-algorithm-scratch-python/) as a guide.

Trying to teach it a simple XOR operation (using various number of hidden layers and neurons on those layers) for the input of `(1, 1), (1, 0), (1, 0), (0, 0)` it tends to output `0.63 0.51 0.51 0.4` instead of `0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0` (I don't expect the exact values, but "almost" ones and "almost" zeros).

I'm hunting that bug for the third day now. Can you spot the mistake?

```cpp
class Network {
public:
  Network(
    std::vector<int> layers // how many neurons on each layer
  ):
    layers(layers)
  {
    for(int l = 0; l < layers.size(); l++) {
      weights.emplace_back();
      outputs.emplace_back();
      errors.emplace_back();

      if(l > 0) {
        for(int n = 0; n < layers[l]; n++) {
          weights[l].emplace_back();
          outputs[l].push_back(0);
          errors[l].push_back(0);
          for(int w = 0; w <= layers[l-1]; w++) {
            weights[l][n].push_back(0);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  std::vector<float> activate(std::vector<float> inputs) {
    outputs[0] = inputs; /* the "outputs" of the first layer are the inputs  */
    for(int l = 1; l < layers.size(); l++)
      for(int n = 0; n < layers[l]; n++) {
        float sum = weights[l][n][layers[l-1]]; // bias
        for(int w = 0; w < layers[l-1]; w++) {
          sum += outputs[l-1][w];
        }
        outputs[l][n] = transfer(sum);
      }
    return outputs[layers.size()-1];
  }

  void randomize(float min, float max) {
    std::random_device e;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(min, max);

    for(int l = 1; l < layers.size(); l++)
      for(int n = 0; n < layers[l]; n++)
        for(int w = 0; w <= layers[l-1]; w++)
          weights[l][n][w] = dis(e);
  }

  float transfer(float sum) {
    return 1 / (1 + exp(-sum));
  }

  float transfer_derivative(float output) {
    return (output) * (1 - output);
  }

  void train(std::vector<float> inputs, std::vector<float> expected, float learning_rate) {
    activate(inputs);

    // calculate the errors of output layer
    for(int n = 0; n < layers[layers.size() - 1]; n++) {
      errors[layers.size() - 1][n] = (expected[n] - outputs[layers.size() - 1][n]) * transfer_derivative(outputs[layers.size() - 1][n]);
    }

    // calculate the errors of hidden layers
    for(int l = layers.size() - 2; l > 0; l--) { // for every HIDDEN layer, last to first
      for(int n = 0; n < layers[l]; n++) {
        float error = 0;
        for(int nln = 0; nln < layers[l+1]; nln++) { // nln == next layer neuron
          error += weights[l+1][nln][n] * errors[l+1][nln];
        }
        errors[l][n] = error * transfer_derivative(outputs[l][n]);
      }
    }

    // adjust the weights
    for(int l = 1; l < layers.size(); l++) {
      for(int n = 0; n < layers[l]; n++) {
        for(int w = 0; w < layers[l - 1]; w++) {
          weights[l][n][w] += learning_rate * errors[l][n] * outputs[l-1][w];
        }
        weights[l][n][layers[l-1]] += learning_rate * errors[l][n];
      }
    }
  }

  std::vector<int> layers;  // how many neurons on each layer
  std::vector<std::vector<float>> outputs;  // [layer][neuron on that layer] = the output of that neuron
  std::vector<std::vector<float>> errors;  // like above, errors
  std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<float>>> weights;  // [layer][neuron on that layer][number of input (i.e. neuron on previous layer)] = weight
};
```

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to debug a bit further on your own. This specific question doesn't lead so well to Q&A. What are the chances someones else would come with this exact problem ?  There's very little comments in the code, and you're not asking a pointed question about a specific behaviour.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding your code. A desperate solution : you can start over, sometimes it works

Comment: I was hoping that someone very familiar with this algorithm will just take a look and say: you're multiplying this and this instead of that. I have compared my implementation with at least four articles and images, couldn't find the mistake...

Comment: please provide a [mre]. What is your training data? What is the learning rate? How many training cycles have you tried? Try passing a range of possible input values and plot the outputs on an image, you should see high responses in the 1,0 and 0,1 corners and low responses in the other 2 corners. XOR is tricky with back propagation: https://dev.to/jbahire/demystifying-the-xor-problem-1blk